# replace string datetime to epoch in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

My Dataframe looks like:

`Time,User,value
2018-03-30T14:18:49.600,U101,23
2018-03-30T14:18:49.800,U102,22
2018-03-30T14:18:50.000,U101,24`

I would like to change String timestamp to epoch in milliseconds in column `Time` in DataFrame. I am able to do that by saving values in list of lists and iterate over each row. But I need an efficient way such that, I can replace String time to epoch time in Dataframe itself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think need convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then to `numpy array` with cast to `int64` and last divide by `10**6` because native format is in `nanosecond`s:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).values.astype(np.int64) // 10**6
print (df)
            Time  User  value
0  1522419529600  U101     23
1  1522419529800  U102     22
2  1522419530000  U101     24
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Time'] = (df['Time'] - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
```

is the recommended solution from pandas, [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html?highlight=Epoch).

example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Time'] = pd.date_range('2012-10-08 18:15:05', periods=4, freq='D')
df['Epoch'] = (df['Time'] - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
print(df)
```

output:

```
                 Time       Epoch
0 2012-10-08 18:15:05  1349720105
1 2012-10-09 18:15:05  1349806505
2 2012-10-10 18:15:05  1349892905
3 2012-10-11 18:15:05  1349979305
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what 'epoch' is for you, but in general the `pandas.apply` function is what you want. It works similar to what `map` is in the python builtin functions. (Assuming that `timestamp.epoch` returns the epoch of a timestamp)

```
import datetime as dt 
def helper(val):
   time = dt.datetime.strptime(dtstring, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
   return dt.epoch()
df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(helper)
```